# Backward heat equation

Tags: ap.analysis-of-pdes, parabolic-pde

I have seen many countre examples concerning the instability and the ill-posedness of the backward heat equation, but all these examples are done in the $||.||_{\infty}$. My questions are:

1) Is the backward heat equation is well-posed in the $||.||_2$ norm (in the Sobolev space setting)?

2) Is it stable (in the Sobolev space setting)?

Comment: No. There is backwards uniqueness for the heat equation (see Evans Chapter 2) but there is no sense in which the backwards heat equation is well-posed (solutions can only exist for infinitely differentiable initial data, which makes it severely ill-posed).